# Is it possible to make an UIMenuItem not clickable in the UIMenuController in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to keep an UIMenuItem to show but not clickable, just show it as a label.

Is it possible to make an UIMenuItem not clickable in the UIMenuController in iOS ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is NO. It is not possible. Since it is not a view subclass, you can't tamper with it.

<strike>**What you can do?**

You can disable some of the menu items for your custom classes. You can do this by responding `NO`in the overridden `canPerformAction:withSender:` method. While this will give you buttons that you can't click, you can't customize it.</strike>

Comment: If it is set to "NO", that button totally disappears. Would you please clarify the behavior ? Thanks.

Comment: You are right. I was mistaken about the disabled state. Edited my answer.